# HTTP Error: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: apache-2.2, php, vps, httpd.conf, web-services

**What I have:**
I have an iPhone app that sends HTTP POST requests (XML format) to a web service written in PHP. This is on a [hosted virtual private server](http://dreamhost.com/servers/vps/) so I can edit `httpd.conf` and other files on the server, and restart Apache.

**The problem:**
The web service works perfectly as long as the request is not too large, but around 1MB is the limit. After that, the server responds with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />/<br />
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data
provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
</body></html>
```

The web service writes its own log file, and I can see that small messages are processed fine. Larger messages are not logged at all so I guess that something in Apache rejects them before they even reach the web service?

**Things I've tried without success:**
(I've restarted Apache after every change. These steps are incremental.)

1. hosting provider's web-based configuration panel: disable mod_security
2. httpd.conf: `LimitXMLRequestBody 0` and `LimitRequestBody 0`
3. httpd.conf: `LimitXMLRequestBody 100000000` and `LimitRequestBody 100000000`
4. httpd.conf: `SecRequestBodyLimit 100000000`

At this stage, Apache's `error.log` contains a message:
`ModSecurity: Request body no files data length is larger than the configured limit (1048576)`

The fact that there's an error statement by ModSecurity indicates that my step #1 didn't really take. Apache's `access.log` looks like this, with 3 successful small messages and 2 failed large messages:

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 310 "-" "Audiopad/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.4 Darwin/11.0.0"
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 310 "-" "Audiopad/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.4 Darwin/11.0.0"
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 310 "-" "Audiopad/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.4 Darwin/11.0.0"
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 413 464 "-" "Audiopad/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.4 Darwin/11.0.0"
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 413 464 "-" "Audiopad/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.4 Darwin/11.0.0"
```

Apache's `error.log` has this info about the large messages:

```
[error] [client 194.24.138.43] ModSecurity: Request body no files data length is larger than the configured limit (1048576). [hostname "webservice-audiopad.golfbravo.net"] [uri "/"]
[error] [client 194.24.138.43] ModSecurity: Request body no files data length is larger than the configured limit (1048576). [hostname "webservice-audiopad.golfbravo.net"] [uri "/"]
```

However, I don't see the value `1048576` anywhere in `httpd.conf`.

**What more can I try, to get the web service to receive large messages?**

Comment: How about `SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit`? Did you take a look at the Apache's error_log after restarting to make sure that mod_security was disabled?

Comment: The method of disabling `mod_security` may have been to set it to `DetectionOnly` rather than removing the module.  It doesn't say anything in that error message about denying the request and it would normally send a 403 if it were working properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I set `SecRequestBodyAccess Off` for now and that solved all problems.

Comment: Where do i add this? In my httpd.conf file?

Comment: Sorry that's three year's ago and I don't run that services anymore. I can't help you...

Comment: `SecRequestBodyAccess` is a basic setting of ModSecurity, usually found in `modsecurity.conf` e.g. at `/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf`.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same exact issue.

SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit was the reason.

it was not used in my config at all, but it does have a default value, 1048576.

Once I found that this setting existed, I set it larger than my files and everything is working.

Here is the documentation https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#wiki-SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit

if you compare to the entry above SecRequestBodyLimit the documentation seems very convoluted.  What I was able to boil it down to is this; If you're uploading an actual file attachment the prior setting will rule. If you are pasting the contents of a file into something like a form and the payload is in the PUT then SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit rules.

Answer (score 3):

You say this is a PHP service, so that means that php.ini is ever bit as much in play as httpd.conf.

There are a number of size limits defined in php.ini, including limits on the size of requests, so I'd start by verifying those limits are all big enough for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good hint! I must find the php.ini (it won't be in the standard location because it's a virtual private server) and check for any limits. But the log indicates that ModSecurity is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Everything I have tried to fix this has failed. One last search and found this here.

SecRequestBodyAccess Off

That did the trick. I know this is 10  years old but sure did help me!